# How is an Xfinity coax jack activated?

Tags: circuit-breaker, cables, coaxial-cable, internet, network

I recently moved into a new flat that primarily accepted Xfinity, as it's considered LIHTC, so a lot of their residents are on the Internet Essentials plan.

I had opted to get my Xfinity router/modem delivered to me, and I thought activating it would be a piece of cake. However, upon connecting everything to the appropriate jacks, I found that although I could connect to the WiFi network, I was unable to get a signal. I even opened the XFinity app to try and activate it, but I unfortunately got locked out of my account and couldn't reset my password, so they finally agreed to send out a tech over to see what they could do.

Well, according to what they told me, the jack was not even transmitting a usable signal, but they were somehow able to get it working without having to leave the unit.

Is there any way I could've done this myself and thus avoid a $100 service charge if there was a switch on the circuit breaker or summoned my building's maintenance tech ahead of time?

Comment: I'd guess it's something they needed to activate on their end - ie it's a software switch they needed to flip. I don't know whether that's something they have an interface for in the app, or whether customer service could do it. Maybe they sent a tech because it wasn't clear if they was other physical damage they needed to fix.

Comment: I just went through the very same problem.  New condo, new equipment.  Could get the local WiFi working but no internet or TV.  Turned out the cable to my unit had been cut where they had been running new cable underground.  When we were finally able to get a tech to come out, he verified in 5 minutes that we did not have a signal, found the cut cable, and made the appropriate repairs.

Comment: So yes, as Jack said, you may have been able to do this yourself.  The biggest problem in many cases is figuring out where the "main" feed comes into your unit from the outside distribution panel.  It may behind a wall plate with a splitter (or two) in the wall cavity - not readily apparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the jack was not connected at the other end.  I.e. the cable running through the wall was not connected.  The tech would have then physically connected the cable.  If you knew where the other end of the cable was and the port was not terminated, you probably could have done this.  It's basically a matter of screwing the cable onto the port.

If you have several jacks, they may have to choose which to connect.  The others just hang free until needed.  They don't connect all of them because each time the signal is split, it loses power.  If it's in the unit, this would probably be close to the circuit breaker, but it has nothing to do with the circuit breaker switches.  Coax is not powered.  The tech might have unscrewed one cable and screwed on the cable that actually goes to the jack that you want to use.

It's possible that the port to which you would have connected was terminated.  That requires a special tool to remove the terminator from the port.  Basically the terminator is designed to spin rather than unscrew.  The tool reaches in to the part that is actually screwed onto the port and allows the user to unscrew that.  That special tool is not generally available.  Only techs are supposed to have it.

It's possible that there was a filter on the port.  That would allow a television signal but block the modem signal.  That used to be common.  You could have removed the filter and reattached the cable to the port without it.

As suggested in a comment, it is possible that there was something in software, but I would have expected a phone call to resolve that without a tech.  It is generally a matter of connecting cables to activate a jack, not software.  It is possible that the place where the cable needed to be connected was behind a lock to which the tech had a key (not like a normal lock that you would use on a door, more like a locking lug nut on a car wheel).  Or it may have been somewhere accessible to you.  Part of the tech's training is finding the place where the cable needs to be connected.

I used to install cable modems.  The company for which I worked sold that part of their business to Comcast.  At that time, the TV signal was unencrypted, so they terminated all ports when not in use.  More modernly, the signal is digitized and needs to be decrypted by a cable box, so they can just leave everything connected or at most unscrewed.  They don't have to bother with terminators.

Anyway, the answer to your question is that we can't know.  If the place where the cable needed to be connected was accessible to you, then you could have done it yourself.  If not, then you couldn't.  The person who could have answered that was the tech.  If you could show us before and after pictures of what the tech changed, then perhaps we could tell you.  But without that, it's simple speculation.  Even if you called Xfinity, they probably wouldn't know.  Only the tech that came to your house actually knows what that tech did.

Answer (score 2):

Since you stated that the tech fixed it without leaving the unit and it as a new flat, my theory is that the main cable was run from outside into a utility closet or remote location in your unit. Then, from there, individual cables were run to other rooms in your unit but the splitter was never installed to join all the cables. So the tech just had to hook your hot main line to a splitter and then connect the other lines to it or just connect your main line to the cable for the outlet you were going to use. This is how many subdivisions I've worked in were wired for cable.

If you had known about this and the jacks were installed on the cable ends, you might have been able to do this yourself.